# How this works: ping computer name

Tags: windows, networking

I am just wondering how this works in the situation:
Two of my computers (OS=Windows) are in same subnet and workgroup. There is no DNS and WINS set. But I can ping each other with the computer names.

when I perform nslookup, like "nslookup PC-A",  no valid record is found
when I perform ping, like "ping PC-A", it works.

Any answer is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NetBIOS allows your computer to "discover" names by basically broadcasting. An example would be like this:

```
1) You ping PC-B
2) Your PC (PC-A) broadcasts via NETBIOS: "Who has PC-B? Reply to x.x.x.x"
3) PC-B sees the response, responds "PC-B is at x.x.x.x"
4) PC-A takes this result, resolves the name.
```

And you're done. This is essentially the same as a DNS lookup except you're asking the network instead of a DNS server. The same behavior is done with ARP for MAC->IP mappings.

The specific behavior is from [NETBIOS-NS](http://wiki.wireshark.org/NetBIOS/NBNS).

Comment: Thanks.
Today I encountered a strange event, after I changed the DHCP reserved IP for PC-A, when I ping PC-A (joined domain abc.com), the DNS suffix is auto appended, it resolves the updated IP, however, if I remove the DNS suffix append, ping PC-A resolved the old IP. What would be the cause? is this a DNS issue? or related to NetBIOS?

Comment: @user3162764 DNS caching. Run a `ipconfig /flushdns` and try again.

Answer (score 4):

take a look at following: [NetBIOS - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS)

Comment: then if the computer joins a domin(abc.com), and there is DNS server, is that correct?
ping PC-A (NETBOIS)
ping PC-A.abc.com (DNS)

Comment: i believe this is correct.

Comment: OS's employ a name resolution order, which defines what means and in what order they will attempt to identify a name. usually they start with the hosts/lmhosts file on the local system, then DNS, and then NETBIOS broadcast. thats why you can override a DNS name by adding it to your hosts file.

Comment: @alexus Try outlining the article some in your answer to give the user a bit more information instead of just linking